# Entity Framework (db-first approach): how to generate entities and mapping in separate layer?

Tags: entity-framework

I want to generate entities and mappings in separate layers.

I try to use the following command in the package manager console to generate entities:

```
scaffold-DbContext "Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=MyDb;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=my;Password=123" Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer
     -OutputDir DataAccess\Entities -f -Verbose -t My_tbl1, My_Payment, tbl1
```

In Entity Framework and database first approach all entities, mapping and context are generated in a layer. But this causes problems with the absence of a separation of concern.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the Entity definitions and Mapping to be managed separately, then you also probably don't want them updated automatically.  So you could just generate them once with scaffold-DbContext, and then manually split them and keep them updated manually with any database changes you want reflected in your project.  Or rerun scaffold-DbContext in another project and cut-and-paste.

If you want to customize the scaffolding process, EF Core doesn't really have anything built-in, but there's some add-ons that will help.  [Entity Framework Core Scaffolding with Handlebars](https://github.com/TrackableEntities/EntityFrameworkCore.Scaffolding).  And some hooks that you can use to customize the type generation yourself. [Entity Framework Core Customize Scaffolding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40728223/entity-framework-core-customize-scaffolding)

Comment: yes good answer, But in general this is a very obvious problem