# Scaffold EF Core entities with interface

Tags: entity-framework-core, ef-core-2.2

I am using [Entity Framework Core tools](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/cli/powershell) to create Entities and DBContext from the existing database.

```
Scaffold-DbContext "Server=XXXXXX;Database=MyDB;User ID=xxxx;Password=xxxxxxx" Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer -ContextDir .-OutputDir Entities -Force
```

This working. But is there any way to scaffold all the entities with known interface? So i have interface `IEntityBase` and i want all the entities to have this interface

Note
This question is specific to EF Core 2+ and scaffolding

**Update 1**
So as per the [SO Suggesion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40728223/entity-framework-core-customize-scaffolding) i have created `CSharpEntityTypeGenerator` and `IDesignTimeServices` The accepted answer is not valid for EF Core > 2.* so i am using the suggession from @Chris Peacock

```
public class MyEntityTypeGenerator: CSharpEntityTypeGenerator
{
    public MyEntityTypeGenerator(ICSharpHelper cSharpHelper)
        : base(cSharpHelper)
    {
    }

    public override string WriteCode(IEntityType entityType, string @namespace, bool useDataAnnotations)
    {
        string code = base.WriteCode(entityType, @namespace, useDataAnnotations);

        var oldString = "public partial class " + entityType.Name;
        var newString = "public partial class " + entityType.Name + " : EntityBase";

        return code.Replace(oldString, newString);
    }
}


public class MyDesignTimeServices: IDesignTimeServices
{
    public void ConfigureDesignTimeServices(IServiceCollection serviceCollection)
    {
        serviceCollection.AddSingleton<ICSharpEntityTypeGenerator, MyEntityTypeGenerator>();
    }
}
```

There is one change i had to make. `CSharpEntityTypeGenerator` constructor takes `ICSharpHelper` as parameter instead of `ICSharpUtilities`

These two classes are in `Data` assembly which is not a startup project.

At package manager console i executed the scaffolding command again. However i do not see generated entities have base class.

How scaffolding framework would know to use my custom generator? I am adding generator in `serviceCollection` but looks like the code never get executed

Am i missing something?

Comment: @AdamVincent it is not duplicate. My question is related to .net core and specific to Scaffolding using EF Core tools. At least it is not same as what you have linked

Comment: Just to be clear, you want the scaffolding operation to append `.. : IEntityBase` on all your classes that are generated from the db?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Entity Framework Core Customize Scaffolding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40728223/entity-framework-core-customize-scaffolding)

Comment: @AdamVincent yes but .net.core using EF Core

Answer (score 3):

You can use EF Core Power Tools with Handlebars templates to achieve this.

https://github.com/ErikEJ/EFCorePowerTools/wiki/Reverse-Engineering#customize-code-using-handlebars

Comment: I have downloaded power tool but it doesnt support adding base class/interface out of the box. As you mentioned i have to use Handlebars. I decided stick to C#  approach :). I would have to use power tool if it simply provide a text box to enter base class or interface name. For more complex customization may use Handlebars

Answer (score 2):

*I think these options should have been provided as as a part of EF Scaffolding tool by default.*

But here is my code. I am using `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design 2.2.4` and `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer 2.2.4` and based on my experience with .NET Core this may change in future version

**CSharpEntityTypeGenerator**

```
public class MyEntityTypeGenerator: CSharpEntityTypeGenerator
{
    public MyEntityTypeGenerator(ICSharpHelper cSharpUtilities)
        : base(cSharpUtilities)
    {
    }

    public override string WriteCode(IEntityType entityType, string @namespace, bool useDataAnnotations)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(entityType.Name);

        string code = base.WriteCode(entityType, @namespace, useDataAnnotations);

        var oldString = "public partial class " + entityType.Name;
        var newString = "public partial class " + entityType.Name + " : EntityBase";

        return code.Replace(oldString, newString);
    }
}
```

By default scaffolding generates classes with the same name as Table name. In our case the table names are Pluralize, but we want class name Singularize. So you have to implement `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.IPluralizer`. I used [Inflator](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Inflector/) utility. However,  note that i could not add `Inflector` using Nuget in .Net Core project. Looks like it does not support .NET Core yet. So i have added [the single code file](https://github.com/markrendle/Inflector/blob/master/Inflector/Inflector.cs) instead in my project.

**IPluralizer**

```
public class MyPluralizer : IPluralizer
{
    public string Pluralize(string identifier)
    {
        return Inflector.Pluralize(identifier) ?? identifier;
    }

    public string Singularize(string identifier)
    {
        return Inflector.Singularize(identifier) ?? identifier;
    }
}
```

**IDesignTimeServices**
You need to add this class in startup project. Initially, i had this class in the same project as other classes but that did not work. I moved this class in startup project, (In my case that is ASP.NET Core project) and it worked

```
public class MyDesignTimeServices : IDesignTimeServices
{
    public void ConfigureDesignTimeServices(IServiceCollection serviceCollection)
    {
        // Start debugger
        System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Launch();
        serviceCollection.AddSingleton<ICSharpEntityTypeGenerator, MyEntityTypeGenerator>();
        serviceCollection.AddSingleton<IPluralizer, MyPluralizer>();
    }
}
```

Comment: For info there have been changes to pluralization in EFCore 3, only just looking at it myself but the following link may be of use to people - https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/17401

Comment: Especially "You need to add this class in startup project. Initially, i had this class in the same project as other classes but that did not work. I moved this class in startup project, (In my case that is ASP.NET Core project) and it worked" worked for me too