# EF Core Scaffold Custom Entities and DBContext

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, ef-core-3.1

I'm using EF Core anf DB First Approach. I generate my dbcontext and entities class using `dotnet ef dbcontext scaffold` and it gave me expected result.

Then i need to add custom implementation in my dbcontext and entity class, but whenever i update my db, and re-scaffold it, all the files is replaced and all my custom implementation is gone also. How to scaffold both context and entity but with some custom configuration?

Here's example what I aim

I have `BaseEntity.cs` class

```
public class BaseEntity
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public bool Deleted { get; set; }
    public string CreatedBy { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreatedTime { get; set; }
    public string LastModifiedBy { get; set; }
    public DateTime? LastModifiedTime { get; set; }
}
```

and my entity will look like this

```
public partial class Education : BaseEntity
{
    public Education()
    {
        EducationDetail = new HashSet<EducationDetail>();
    }
    public int UserProfileId { get; set; }
    public int EnumEducationId { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime? EndDate { get; set; }

    public virtual EnumEducation EnumEducation { get; set; }
    public virtual UserProfile UserProfile { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<EducationDetail> EducationDetail { get; set; }
}
```

But if i re-scaffold, it will become

```
public partial class Education 
{
    public Education()
    {
        EducationDetail = new HashSet<EducationDetail>();
    }
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public bool Deleted { get; set; }
    public string CreatedBy { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreatedTime { get; set; }
    public string LastModifiedBy { get; set; }
    public DateTime? LastModifiedTime { get; set; }
    public int UserProfileId { get; set; }
    public int EnumEducationId { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime? EndDate { get; set; }

    public virtual EnumEducation EnumEducation { get; set; }
    public virtual UserProfile UserProfile { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<EducationDetail> EducationDetail { get; set; }
}
```

can i custom the scaffold? i found [Entity Framework Core Customize Scaffolding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40728223/entity-framework-core-customize-scaffolding), but i think it's no longer available / supported by microsoft

Any way around?

Answer (score 2):

## Option 1

Use [partial classes](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/partial-classes-and-methods). This works well when **strictly adding** to the classes. Unfortunately, it doesn't work well for your scenario since some of the generated properties would need to `override` the base members. But it would however work if you used an interface instead.

```cs
partial class Education : IEntity
{
}
```

## Options 2

Use templates. This gives you complete control of the generated code. The [EntityFrameworkCore.Scaffolding.Handlebars](https://github.com/TrackableEntities/EntityFrameworkCore.Scaffolding.Handlebars) package enables templates via [handlebars](https://handlebarsjs.com/guide/). The [EFCore.TextTemplating](https://github.com/bricelam/EFCore.TextTemplating) sample shows how use [T4 templates](https://learn.microsoft.com/visualstudio/modeling/writing-a-t4-text-template).

```
<#@ parameter name="EntityType" type="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.IEntityType" #>
<#@ parameter name="Code" type="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.ICSharpHelper" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Linq" #>
<#@ import namespace="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore" #>
<#
    var baseProperties = new[]
    {
        "Id",
        "Deleted",
        "CreatedBy",
        "CreatedTime",
        "LastModifiedBy",
        "LastModifiedTime"
    };
#>
public partial class <#= EntityType.Name #> : BaseEntity
{
    <# foreach (var property in EntityType.GetProperties()
        .Where(p => !baseProperties.Contains(p.Name))) { #>
        
    public <#= Code.Reference(property.ClrType) #> <#= property.Name #> { get; set; }
    
    <# } #>
}
```