# implement Base Entity inheritance with CSharpEntityTypeGenerator (EF Core DB First Approach)

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, ef-code-first

I'm trying to create database entities inherited by BaseEntity on DB first approach like this:

```
    public partial class BaseEntity
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public DateTime CreatedAt { get; set; }
        public DateTime UpdatedAt { get; set; }
    }

    public partial class Customer: BaseEntity
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public DateTime CreatedAt { get; set; }
        public DateTime UpdatedAt { get; set; }
    }
```

I Achiced this by "CSharpEntityTypeGenerator", but I don't want duplicate members on my entities. as you can see, "Id", "CreatedAt" and "UpdatedAt" should not be on the Customer Entity. Does anyone know how I can achieve this on scaffolding?

Additional resources:

[Entity Framework Core Customize Scaffolding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40728223/entity-framework-core-customize-scaffolding)

Comment: It could probably be done, but that's not a good solution IMHO. No need to reinvent the wheel, you'd better look at this extensions [EntityFrameworkCore.Scaffolding.Handlebars](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/extensions/#entityframeworkcorescaffoldinghandlebars) or [EF Core Power Tools](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/extensions/#ef-core-power-tools)

Comment: @IvanStoev I used this extension, but the problem is, every time I scaffold my database Entities, it will add baseEntity members to all entities. the point is, I'm looking for a way to prevent that. until now I didn't find this feature in EF Core Power Tools.

Comment: By my understanding Handlebars should allow you to do whatever you like w/o dealing with EFC (constantly changing) internals. But can't say 100% since never used/tried these. That's why just commenting. Good luck.