# Entity Framework auto generate DbContext class from database table in C# preserve virtual property

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I have some tables that have some property modifiers set to virtual. I want to be able to auto-generate a `DbContext` class without stripping those virtual keywords from the properties.

I've tried `dotnet ef dbcontext scaffold` but it strips virtual out.

I've also tried `dotnet ef dbcontext update` but I get an error that states update isn't a recognized cmdlet.

I'm using EF Core 5.0. Can someone please help with this if it is even possible? I've googled for a solution but couldn't find one.

Comment: The C# scaffolder replaces the entire file. You could replace the `CSharpEntityTypeGenerator` service with your own implementation that overrides `GenerateProperties` (see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40728223/entity-framework-core-customize-scaffolding / https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/blob/main/src/EFCore.Design/Scaffolding/Internal/CSharpEntityTypeGenerator.cs#L264).

Comment: Once you get some more experience, you'll realize you want to write the DBContext yourself. Those scaffolding tools are nice, but just a gimmick.