# Can foreign key constraints be skipped when generating models with Scaffold-DbContext?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework-core, ef-core-6.0

I'm using this command to generate models:

```
Scaffold-DbContext "Data Source=;Initial Catalog=;Integrated Security=True;Command Timeout=3000;" Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer -NoOnConfiguring -UseDatabaseNames -OutputDir "" -Context "" -ContextDir "" -Force -Tables ""
```

I'm some issues with using the models because I can't have all the extra properties that are generated from the foreign key constraints. The model might look something like this:

```
public Guid Id { get; set; }
public byte[] Timestamp { get; set; } = null!;
public Guid Company { get; set; }

public virtual Company Company { get; set; } = null!;
```

I'm trying to avoid having the last property generated and thought I could do so by skipping  generating foreign key constraints. I was unsuccessful finding anything in the docs. Any ideas what I could do here?

Comment: You can replace the CSharpDbContextGenerator https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40728223/entity-framework-core-customize-scaffolding or maybe the RelationalScaffoldingModelFactory service. Though EF Core 7 may swap to using editable text templates; https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-7.0/plan#database-scaffolding-templates